# Scala 2.11.4, akka 2.3.7, spray 1.3.1 giving type mismatch error

Tags: scala, akka, spray

I am new to Scala. While trying spray with akka I am getting the following error

```
Error:(17, 17) type mismatch;
 found   : String("Welcome to Scala")
 required: spray.httpx.marshalling.ToResponseMarshallable
       complete("Welcome to Scala")
```

Code:

```
import spray.routing._
import akka.actor._
object SampleApplication extends App with SimpleRoutingApp {
  implicit val actorSystem = ActorSystem()
  startServer(interface = "localhost", port = 8080) {
    get {
      path("hello") {
        complete {
          "Welcome to Scala"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Maven Dependencies:

```
  <dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
  <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
  <version>${scala.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.specs</groupId>
  <artifactId>specs</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.5</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.spray</groupId>
  <artifactId>spray-routing</artifactId>
  <version>${spray.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.spray</groupId>
  <artifactId>spray-can</artifactId>
  <version>${spray.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.spray</groupId>
  <artifactId>spray-httpx</artifactId>
  <version>${spray.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.spray</groupId>
  <artifactId>spray-client</artifactId>
  <version>${spray.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.spray</groupId>
  <artifactId>spray-json_2.11</artifactId>
  <version>${spray.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
  <artifactId>akka-actor_2.11</artifactId>
  <version>${akka.version}</version>
</dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Ide used is intellij Idea 14

Are dependencies strictly bind to scala version?

Please help in solving the issue.

Comment: your example runs fine - how do you run it? ide, sbt ....?

Comment: Using maven and Intellij IDEA

Comment: how can anybody help you with your provided infos? - you should provide this in your question - include your maven config - or better: a link to your project at github or bitbucket ...

Comment: sorry. Please check. I have updated the question

Answer (score 0):

Your example works for me. I suspect something шы wrong with your dependencies which causes `spray.httpx.marshalling` not to be found.

Overall I highly recommend not to use Maven with Scala and stick to SBT instead. With SBT you get access to the same dependencies (just like in Maven), but also can directly specify dependency from GitHub. You will also get incremental compilation. Ability to start shell or servlet container within sbt is also convenient. If you use Intellij IDEA it can open SBT configuration as project. And it comes with make tasks you'd probably need (test, run, doc, publish-local, console).

Comment: can you please share why sbt is preffered over maven?